# what is in java importing packages

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class createfile{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

File f=new File("javafile.txt");

if(f.exists())

{

f.createNewFile();

System.out.println("New file \"javafile.txt\"has been created to the current directory");

}

else

System.out.println("The specified file is already exist");

}
}
```

I created a existing file "javafile.txt". i entered some text into this.. If i compile javac, i hope that file must be recreated by the following codes

```
if(f.exists())    
{    
   f.createNewFile();
}
```

but it didn't create.. when i open it, the existing file opens. why?

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't see how the title fits with the body.

Comment: Where's implementation for `createNewFile()`?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File.createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) create new file if not exists already.

```
public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException
```

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname **if and only if a file with
>   this name does not yet exist**. The check for the existence of the file
>   and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single
>   operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem
>   activities that might affect the file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname **if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist**.

This is exactly how the method is supposed to work.